# Using Preseed/Kickstart with USB

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb, preseed, kickstart

Has anyone successfully created a bootable USB key that will use preseed and kickstart?
All the tutorials titled 'automated install ubuntu with usb' etc, have `cdrom/..` as the iso path.

When i attempt to burn my finished iso to a USB key it goes to an interactive install. I assume because it cannot find the files. USB on the hardware is `/dev/sdb1`

My config files would be from here: http://gyk.lt/ubuntu-14-04-desktop-unattended-installation/

Many thanks,

L